# Connect 3g obd II to azure iot hub

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, 3g, obd-ii

I am new to azure iot and I am trying to connect a 3g obd 2 tracker to my account azure iot hub. I found an example to connect the obd to local gateway (phone) via bluetooth or wifi but I want the tracker to be completely independant from any local gateway.
Is there a tutorial or documentation to help me getting starting with connecting 3g teacker to azure iot

Answer (score 0):

There is no tutorial specifically on 3G trackers.  What is the OS running on the device?  You can always use the [device SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks) to connect to IoT Hub directly if your device is IP capable.

Comment: There is no specific device for the moment, I am preparing for a project and doing my research, I want to connect a gps tracker with gsm/gprs/3g module to the azure iot hub, I can find documentation for devices powered by arduino or raspberry but not for industrial gos devices